# Python Regex - Unknown extension "?>"

Tags: python, regex

I have a simple regex pattern that the python re library claims it's unable to interpret. Specifically the ? + some character. This is the regex pattern im trying to compile:

- **(?>\d\d){1,2}**

Entire code snippet:

```
import re
restr = r"\(?>\d\d){1,2}"
string = "12"

regex = re.compile(restr)

regex.search(string)
```

Error returned:

```
File "C:\Users\~USER~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\sre_parse.py", line 823, in _parse
    raise source.error("unknown extension ?" + char,
re.error: unknown extension ?> at position 1
```

i've searched high and low an can't seem to find the cause of the issue. All the help is greatly appreciated. I've read about the re flags and different matching methods but it's just the characters that do not work.

Comment: `?` has special meaning in regex so shouldn't it be escaped - `\?`

Comment: What Python version are you using ?  `Python supports atomic grouping and possessive quantifiers starting with Python version 3.11.`

Comment: Using version 3.9. Just updated it to 3.11 and it works just fine. Read the notes of 3.11 and you're right. Please post your recommendation as the answer and i'll mark it as a solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python only supports atomic grouping and possessive quantifiers [from version 3.11](https://learnbyexample.github.io/python-regex-possessive-quantifier/).